# Tracking a subdomain separately in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

So I've been trying to set up Google Analytics to track site's (Tumblr) blog separately from the rest of the site, but I've been having no luck. All of the tutorials online seem to be outdated, and Google's own help center isn't helping.

Can someone please help. I tried messing with filters, but simply can't get it to work.

The website is sitename.com and the blog is blog.sitename.com. They both share a tracking code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two Analytics profiles, one for each site.  Then put their respective tracking codes on each site.

Answer (score 2):

Create an a custom include filter on the hostname:
on one profile, include only ^www.domain.com$
on another profile, include only ^blog.domain.com$

Beware that e-Commerce transactions can't be filtered by hostname but only by transaction ID

I encourage you to keep a 3rd profile without filters, to be able to check that you don't miss anything.